# How to get wifi to connect at boot on Centos

Tags: centos, boot, wifi, wpa

I'v got a CentOS 5.3 install that I want to connect to the wifi on boot. As the wifi adapter was installed via ndiswrapper there no /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-wlan0 on the computer.

I tried following this guide: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/WpaSupplicant , however I ended up with strage errors about wpa-supplicant and dbus, although I am pretty sure dbus was running.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to put the command in /etc/init.d/rc.local. You could also write a proper init script, with start and stop commands and use rcconf to integrate it into the startup/shutdown procedure.

Comment: What command would that be?